# Condensation point of molecule compounds?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

Which of the following gasses will condense at the lowest pressure (Assuming temperature is held constant)?

1. $\ce{CBr4}$
2. $\ce{CH2Br2}$

I believe that compound **2** will condense at the lower pressure because it can form dipole dipole forces with other molecules. I believe that London dispersion forces are weaker than dipole dipole ones so **2** should condensed at a lower pressure.

Comment: Hint: At ambient conditions, $\ce{CBr4}$ is a solid and $\ce{CH2Br2}$ is a liquid.

Comment: I know that you are right but why isn’t the melting point of CH2Br2 higher than CBr4 since CH2Br2 has stronger intermolecular forces.

Comment: A weak man can be weaker than a strong cat. Same thing with dipoles vs London forces. And the dipole moment of C-Br bond, mind you, is pretty weak.

Comment: Since dipole moment is rather weak in $\ce{CH2Br2}$, molecular weight difference dominates.